# java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out after failed request

Tags: java, ssl

In my program I need to execute secured (two-way SSL) requests to two different servers. For now when I try to connect to `server1` I'm getting exception `javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException`. The strangest thing is that I cannot receive response from `server2` after failed request to `server1`. I'm getting exception `java.net.SocketTimeoutException`. If the request to `server1` is not executed `server2` returns the data successfully.

Stack trace:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(Unknown Source)
...
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(Unknown Source)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(Unknown Source)
    ... 20 more

Exception in thread "main": java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(Unknown Source)
    ...
```

Code of the request to `server1`:

```
URL url = ...
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-type", "application/soap+xml; charset=UTF-8");
connection.setConnectTimeout(300000);
connection.setReadTimeout(300000);
connection.setDoInput(true);
connection.setDoOutput(true);
HttpsURLConnection httpsConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) connection;
SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(new File(...));
try {
    keyStore.load(is, "password".toCharArray());
    keyManagerFactory.init(keyStore, "password".toCharArray());
} finally {
    is.close();
}
TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
is = new FileInputStream(new File(...));
try {
    keyStore.load(is, "password".toCharArray());
    trustManagerFactory.init(keyStore);
} finally {
    is.close();
}
sslContext.init(keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers(),
    trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers(),new SecureRandom());
httpsConnection.setSSLSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory());
httpsConnection.setHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
    @Override
    public boolean verify(String s, SSLSession sslSession) {
        return true;
    }
});
try {
    OutputStream os = connection.getOutputStream();
    try {
        String s = ...;
        os.write(s.getBytes());
    } finally {
        os.close();
    }
    System.out.println("Response code: " + connection.getResponseCode());
} finally {
    connection.disconnect();
}
```

Code of the request to `server2`:

```
SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(new File(...));
try {
    keyStore.load(is, "password".toCharArray());
    keyManagerFactory.init(localKeyStore, "password".toCharArray());
} finally {
    is.close();
}
TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
is = new FileInputStream(new File(...));
try {
    keyStore.load(is, "password".toCharArray());
    trustManagerFactory.init(keyStore);
} finally {
    is.close();
}
sslContext.init(keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers(),
    trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers(), new SecureRandom());
URL url = ...
URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
((HttpsURLConnection) connection).setSSLSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory());
connection.setReadTimeout(40000);
connection.setConnectTimeout(40000);
connection.setDoInput(true);
connection.setDoOutput(false);
int respCode = ((HttpURLConnection) connection).getResponseCode();
if (respCode != 200)
    throw new RuntimeException(...);
BufferedInputStream bufferedIs = new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
try {
    byte[] buf = new byte[512];
    int j;
    while ((j = bufferedIs.read(buf)) != -1) {
        ...
} finally {
    bufferedIs.close();
}
```

I would appreciate for any help.

Comment: Are you using two different keystores and truststores? If you are, you shouldn't be, and if you're not, you should use the same SSLContext both times, instead of laboriously constructing it twice.

Comment: @EJP Of course I'm using different key-/truststores for every case. `SSLContext` is created exactly as in code samples - twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Carelessly I have omitted one very important line in my code snippets: `System.setProperty("sun.security.ssl.allowUnsafeRenegotiation", "true")`. That property is set after the request to `server1` and before the request to `server2` and if its value is `false` request to `server2` fails with exception from the subject. After exploring the sources of OpenJDK I found class `com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker` with static and finalized field `boolean allowUnsafeRenegotiation` that is initialized with following method call: `Debug.getBooleanProperty("sun.security.ssl.allowUnsafeRenegotiation", false)`.

So in my case after first request property `sun.security.ssl.allowUnsafeRenegotiation` is initialized with default value (`false`) and any subsequent attempts to change that property have no effect.